# How to add computers to a distribution group using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have created the code below and I am not figuring out who it is not working.  If I do this manually it works but what seems to be the problem is that my variable is not going into the for-eachobject as an array and the entire contents of the variable is being used instead of one computer name at a time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import-module activedirectory
$virtuals = get-adcomputer -filter "Name -like '*v'" | foreach-object{$_.distinguishedname}
foreach-object -inputobject $virtuals {
     Add-ADGroupMember VMs "$_"
}
```

The error I get is:

```
Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'CN=CSD-024V,OU=VM,OU=Workstations,OU=...
' under: 'DC=co,DC=****,DC=wi,DC=us'.
At line:4 char:22
+     Add-ADGroupMember <<<<  VMs "$_"
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (CN=CSD-024V,OU=...ark,DC=wi,DC=us:ADPrincipal) [Add-ADGroupMember], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SetADGroupMember.ValidateMembersParameter,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddADGroupMember
```

Answer (score 1):

That is what's happening. Consider:

```
PS D:\> $nums = 1..5

PS D:\> $nums | ForEach-Object { "* $_ *" }
* 1 *
* 2 *
* 3 *
* 4 *
* 5 *

PS D:\> ForEach-Object -InputObject $nums { "* $_ *" }
* 1 2 3 4 5 *
```

I don't know why that distinction exists, but it is documented in the help, [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849731.aspx):

> When you use the InputObject parameter with ForEach-Object, instead of
>   piping command results to ForEach-Object, the InputObject value is
>   treated as a single object. This is true even if the value is a
>   collection that is the result of a command, such as -InputObject
>   (Get-Process).

So your fix would be:

```
$virtuals | ForEach-Object {
     Add-ADGroupMember VMs "$_"
}
```

---

**Auto-generated PS help links from my codeblock** (if available):

- [`ForEach-Object`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113300)
- [`Add-ADGroupMember`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=219287) (in module `ActiveDirectory`)